# do I have to handle both google+ API and google play game service to use google play game service?

Tags: google-play-services

I'm new to Android and trying to use google play game service for my app.

I found out from Google Developers page that there is a sign in guide in google play game service, but heard that i need to sign in with google+ account to use play game services.

So, my question is "do I need google+ account and also have to develop google+ API on my app to use google play game service?

Sorry my question is pretty messy, though I need help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play Games services features that use authenticated calls, such as posting high scores or joining a real-time multiplayer match, use Google+ sign-in.  You will need to implement sign-in in your app; check out the docs at:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

You can have your game activity extend BaseGameActivity from the sample code and it will do a lots of the work for you.

Usually people refer to the "Google+ API" as the APIs for retrieving social information, like a getting a list of Google+ posts or sharing interactive posts on Google+.  The sign-in is the same (it's obviously also using Google+ sign-in), but to use the Google+ API, you would also need to request additional scopes.  See:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started